# How can I sum the price of the item that I selected from my dropdown that retrieved in the database

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to sum the price after selecting an item in the dropdown, but it only displays NaN. The value of dropdown are retrieved from MySQL database

```
<?php
    //database connection here
?>
    <table border=" 1">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Component</th>
                <th>Item Name</th>
                <th>Price </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>CPU</td>
                <td>
                    <?php
                    //Retrieving CPU table
                    $query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM cpu");
                    echo '<select  onChange = parseFloat($("#cpuprice").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("cpuprice")))>';
                    echo "<option>---select your CPU---</option>";
                    while ($obj = $query->fetch_object()) {
                        echo '<option cpuprice = "' . $obj->price . '" >' . $obj->cpuname . '</option>';
                    }
                    echo '</select>';
                    ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <output class="form-control prc" id="cpuprice" disabled value="">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>GPU</td>
                <td>
                    <?php
                    //Retrieving GPU table
                    $query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM gpu");
                    echo '<select  onChange = parseFloat($("#tpuprice").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("gpuprice")))>';
                    echo "<option>---select your GPU---</option>";
                    while ($obj = $query->fetch_object()) {
                        echo '<option  gpuprice = "' . $obj->price . '" >' . $obj->gpuname . '</option>';
                    }
                    echo '</select>';
                    ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <output class="form-control prc" id="tpuprice" disabled value="">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

this is the jQuery that I used I don't know if this is right but I search everywhere and NaN is the best result I got so far, sorry I'm just new to using JavaScript or jQuery

```
<span class="totalprice">Total: </span>

    <script>
        var total = 0;
            $('select').change(function() {
            var cpu = ($('#totalprice').val($(this).find('option:selected').attr('cpuprice')))
            var gpu = ($('#Totalprice').val($(this).find('option:selected').attr('gpuprice')))
            total = parseFloat(cpu) + parseFloat(gpu);
            $('.totalprice').text('₱' + total);
            })
    </script>
```

here is the picture, after selecting it just NaN:
[image: here is the picture, after selecting it just NaN]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the `attr` exist on not inside option because your first option doesn't have `attr` that's the reason its giving `NaN` so if doesn't exist just give value `0` else attr value .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var total = 0;
$('select').change(function() {
  //get value from cpu slect box check if attr there else take value 0
  var cpu_price = $(".cpu").find('option:selected').attr('cpuprice') ? $(".cpu").find('option:selected').attr('cpuprice') : 0

  $('#cpuprice').val(cpu_price)
  //get value from gpu slect box check if attr there else take value 0
  var gpu_price = $(".gpu").find('option:selected').attr('gpuprice') ? $(".gpu").find('option:selected').attr('gpuprice') : 0
  $('#tpuprice').val(gpu_price)

  total = parseFloat(cpu_price) + parseFloat(gpu_price);
  $('.totalprice').text('₱' + total);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=" 1">

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Component</th>
      <th>Item Name</th>
      <th>Price </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>CPU</td>
      <td>
        <select class="cpu">
          <option>---select your CPU---</option>
          <option cpuprice="1222">Soemthing</option>
          <option cpuprice="1000">Soemthing1</option>
        </select>

      </td>
      <td>
        <output class="form-control prc" id="cpuprice" disabled value="" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>GPU</td>
      <td>
        <select class="gpu">
          <option>---select your GPU---</option>
          <option gpuprice="1200">Somehingg</option>
          <option gpuprice="120">Somehingg1</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <output class="form-control prc" id="tpuprice" disabled value="" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<span class="totalprice">Total: </span>
```